# Combining several NetCDF into a single file with mean values for each dimension

Tags: r, gis, raster, netcdf

I have 3 NetCDF files containing data on the average daily temperature range (dtr) per month between 1981 and 2010. A file covers a period of 10 years, so each pixel has 10 x 12 values (1 value per month x 10 years). The files can be downloaded [here](https://catalogue.ceda.ac.uk/uuid/10d3e3640f004c578403419aac167d82) (a login is required).

I would like to merge all these files into a single one containing the monthly mean dtr for the entire period covered by the 3 files. The idea is to end up with 12 values per pixel (1 average monthly value for 30 years).

I have no previous experience working with NetCDF format and don't really understand its structure. I tried the `NetCDF` function from the `ncdump` package but I did not learn much from it…

Unfortunately, doing the following only compute the mean dtr in 30 years.

```
"GIS/Clim/BioClim/dtr/" %>%
  list.files(pattern = "\\.nc$", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  raster::stack() %>% 
  raster::overlay(fun = mean)
```

Here is what I get when I extract the data from a single pixel in one file:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

p <- tibble(lat = 45.76, lon = -107.12) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

raster::stack("GIS/Clim/dtr/cru_dtr-2001_2010.nc") %>% 
  raster::extract(p, df = TRUE)

# X2001.01.16 X2001.02.15 X2001.03.16 X2001.04.16 X2001.05.16 X2001.06.16
# 1        11.1        11.3        10.8    9.900001    9.800000    9.400001
# X2001.07.16 X2001.08.16 X2001.09.16 X2001.10.16 X2001.11.16 X2001.12.16
# 1   10.100000         8.6   10.200000    9.500000         9.5         9.3
# X2002.01.16 X2002.02.15 X2002.03.16 X2002.04.16 X2002.05.16 X2002.06.16
# 1        10.6        10.7        10.3         9.0    9.600000         9.1
# 
# ...                               ...                               ...
# 
# X2010.07.16 X2010.08.16 X2010.09.16 X2010.10.16 X2010.11.16 X2010.12.16
# 1    9.000000         9.0    8.900001    8.800000         8.3         8.3
```

How could I combine these 3 NetCDF files and compute the monthly mean dtr to create a new NetCDF?

Note that a Python solution also works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to answer as you do not provide some simple example data. But it would be something along these lines

```
library(raster)
filenames <- c("one.nc", "two.nc", "three.nc")
b <- lapply(filenames, brick)
s <- stack(b)
m <- stackApply(s, 1:12, mean)
```